# Ring of Sets Question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I apologize if this has been asked before. I am using Folland's Real Analysis text and on page 23, problem 1, part (c) we are asked to show that if $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\sigma$-ring then $S=\{ E \subset X: E \in \mathcal{R} \text{ or } E^{c} \in \mathcal{R}  \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. My approach was case by case. If $ E_{1},E_{2} \in S$ because $E_{1},E_{2} \in \mathcal{R}$ then it's obvious that $E_{1} \cup E_{2} \in S$. I can also show that $E_{1} \cup E_{2} \in S$ when $E_{1}^{c},E_{2}^{c} \in \mathcal{R}$. My trouble is showing that $E_{1} \cup E_{2} \in S$ when $E_{1},E_{2}^{c} \in \mathcal{R}$. My idea was once these cases were shown, you could separate a general union into a union of the first case and union with the second case and then union those two. We would have something like, let $ \{ E_{i}\} \subset S $, $ K = \{ i: E_{i} \in \mathcal{R} \}$ and $ J =  \{ i: E_{i}^{c} \in \mathcal{R} \} $. Then

$$ \bigcup_{1}^{\infty}E_{i} = \bigcup_{k \in K}^{\infty}E_{k} \cup \bigcup_{j\in J}^{\infty} E_{j} = \bigcup_{k \in K}^{\infty}E_{k} \cup \left[\bigcap_{j \in J}^{\infty} E_{j}^{c} \right]^{c}$$

So $ \bigcup_{k \in K}^{\infty}E_{k} \in \mathcal{R} $ and $ \bigcap_{j \in J}^{\infty} E_{j}^{c} \in \mathcal{R}$, but I don't know that $\left[\bigcap_{j \in J}^{\infty} E_{j}^{c} \right]^{c} \in \mathcal{R} $ and therefore I can't say that the union must be in $\mathcal{R}$. Similar problems arise if I try to show that the complement of this union is in $\mathcal{R}$. Any help is appreciated and I apologize if this is a bit trivial.

Comment: Note that by definition $E_1 \cup E_2 \in S \iff (E_1 \cup E_2)^c \in S$. And $(E_1 \cup E_2)^c = E_1^c \cap E_2^c = E_2^c \setminus E_1$.

Comment: I appreciate the quickness of your reply. I'm slightly confused, my apologies. I'm not sure that I understand the equivalence $ E_{1} \cup E_{2} \in \mathcal{R} \iff (E_{1} \cup E_{2})^{c} \in \mathcal{R}$.

Comment: Sorry, typo. That should be (and now is) $S$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes I see this now! Thank you!